# Jackson SimpleAbstractTypeResolver for List<Interface>

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I have an object that is comprised of interfaces that I need to deserialize using Jackson. Due to the design of the system I cannot specify any annotations in the interface so I need to add the required resolver information to the `ObjectMapper`. My object has the following:

```
private Alarm alarm; // Alarm is an interface
private List<Extra> extra; // Extra is an interface
```

Now I can take care of the Alarm relatively easily using an `AbstractTypeResolver`:

```
SimpleAbstractTypeResolver resolver = new SimpleAbstractTypeResolver();
resolver.addMapping(Alarm.class, AlarmImpl.class);

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.setAbstractTypes(resolver);

mapper.registerModule(module);

mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Engine>>() {});
```

That works great. However, adding the `Extra` resolver in the same way doesn't work:

```
resolver.addMapping(Extra.class, ExtraImpl.class);
```

Any suggestions on how I should be applying it for a list?